# How to create global variable in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I want to create a global variable for my entire project in Laravel's framework, so how I can create it in a class and make it everywhere.
Anyone can guide it?

Answer (score 8):

You can create one file inside the config folder.

**config/global.php**

*//set your array here.*

```
return [

  'siteTitle' => 'HD Site',

  'pagination' => 5,

  'tagLine' => 'Do the best'

];
```

**Use in your view file.**

```
{{ config('global.siteTitle') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new file in config and use

```
  config('your_new_file_name.key')
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use laravel helpers to declare a global variables, you can create your own customize helper function.

See this: [Laravel helper](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers) and this  [Toturial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-laravel-helper--cms-28537)

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 7, I created a GlobalVars class in the /app directory (namespace App), created a static variable $myvar, and then access it in any class by adding 'use App\GlobalVars' and calling 'GlobalVars::$myvar'.